# Return value to the text box where the new form called

Tags: vb.net, textbox, return-value

In my form named 'authors', I have two text fields both of them are for getting two different dates as input. If the user focus the text box it will display the calendar that I have placed in some other form. After selecting the date and clicking the select button, the selected date will be assigned to the text box.

This is the code that I have written:

authors - coding:

```
Private Sub DOFE_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As      System.EventArgs) Handles DOFE.GotFocus
If DOFE.Text = "" Then
        Calendar.ShowDialog()
    Else
        Me.DOFE.Select()
        Me.DOFE.Focus()
    End If
End Sub
```

calender - coding:

```
Private Sub B_SELECT_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles B_SELECT.Click
    Authors.DOFE.Text = Format(MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start(), "dd/MM/yyyy")
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub MonthCalendar1_DateChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DateRangeEventArgs) Handles MonthCalendar1.DateChanged
    Authors.DOFE.Text = Format(MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start(), "dd/MM/yyyy")
End Sub
```

Now the problem is, When I trying to execute the following code:

```
Private Sub DOB_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DOB.GotFocus
    If DOB.Text = "" Then
        Calendar.ShowDialog()
    Else
        Me.DOB.Select()
        Me.DOB.Focus()
    End If
End Sub
```

I mean, this code is for assigning some other date to some other text field of same form.

It is possible by adding single line

```
**Authors.DOB.Text** = Format(MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start(), "dd/MM/yyyy")
```

in calendar form but the reflection will happen to both text field.

Suggest me in this regard.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your problem. You could look at the [ToString function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx) of DateTime, it let you format a date in anyway you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to use a `Public` variable to hold the date and then assign it after the `ShowDialog` method.

So in some module you would have

```
Public tempDate As Date
```

In your calendar code

```
Private Sub B_SELECT_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles B_SELECT.Click
    tempDate = Format(MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start(), "dd/MM/yyyy")
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

And then in your `Text_Changed` events

```
Private Sub DOB_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DOB.GotFocus
    If DOB.Text = "" Then
        tempDate = ""
        Calendar.ShowDialog()
        DOB.Text = tempDate
    Else
        Me.DOB.Select()
        Me.DOB.Focus()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes it works. Thank you. But the problem in your code is, until we assign some text to the text box focus in the text couldn't lost. Because we have GotFocus event. So, I made change like                                                                If DOFE.Text = "" And TempDate = "" Then
            Calendar.ShowDialog()
            DOFE.Text = TempDate
            TempDate = ""
        Else
            Me.DOFE.Select()
            Me.DOFE.Focus()
        End If

Comment: Glad you got it working as you desired. Please select my answer. Thank you.